# On Icon Hover Draw Icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create this Icon Animate effect for my personal work. As they are using images to draw icon on hover. Any other trick to use this one. Please advise

[Live Working Link](http://www.rokivo.com)

http://puu.sh/pAksc/8c81c44718.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man... I think you don't understand at all what you are talking about ...
Here are some things you should try and understand first.

First, have you tried any piece of code or looked for a tutorial ?! Usually if you post a question on Stackoverflow, you're not asking people to do your job, you must first have tried things and have a code example to show...
Start here : https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/ This should do what you want to do.
Then you just have to trigger the animation on `div:hover`

Second this **won't** work with a png. This only work with specific SVG images. First take a look at what an SVG image is and how to work with it in HTML/CSS.

Third you **don't** need **any** jQuery here so leave that aside if that's the only thing that requires jquery in your website.

Comment: Thank You for Response ! I understand now. I am new to Site and surly keep this in mind for next time. FYI

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped ! I didn't mean to sound harsh but that is really the way it works.
If this answer is satisfying to you, consider marking it as the "accepted answer" by ticking the "v" checkmark under the arrows that you use to upvote/downvote. Thanks